# What is a PR-bomb?

Tags: discussion, questions

@TrevorPowell said he deleted a lot of [this question's details](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/has-piracy-ever-resulted-in-a-developer-getting-shut-down/) due to a "PR-BOMB".

I'm not sure what he means by "PR-BOMB"

[image]

To me that question *does* appear to have an agenda of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases it's hard to tell if somebody is bringing up a game/article/whatever because they're curious about it, or if they're [astroturfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing).

Either way, editing down questions so they're more to the point and succinct is usually a good move.

Comment: Astroturfing -- yes that is what that question appears to me as well